# User can update or delete data which created by others

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class StoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = StorySerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
```

I have viewset with all CRUD functions. The problem is that user can edit or delete stories of another user, I found `DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly` in `permissions`, but I cannot even create. I am using `author` as `foreign key` in `Story`model. Also I am using `rest_framework.authtoken`. So, I think there is two options, create own permission or rewrite some permission. Which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a customer object-level permission. Here is an example:

```
class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Object-level permission to only allow owners of an object to edit it.
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return obj.author == request.user
```

And include it to `permission_classes` list.